# Linq to SQL and Collection operations

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, collections

I have a Dictionary which I'd like to use like an IN clause within a SQL query.

I have a Linq-To-SQL query where I would like to use this Dictionary's Keys to check fields in the rows for the query.

E.g.

```
bool result = DataContext.Table.Any(res => MyDictionary.ContainsKey(res.field1));
```

In effect this is similar to

```
    exists(select * from Table where field1 in (select id from DictionaryKeys))
```

where `DictionaryKeys` would be an expansion of the Keys into their own table.

Unfortunately I get

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
Message="Method 'Boolean ContainsKey(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL."
Source="System.Data.Linq"
```

I understand the error, but I'm struggling to think around the problem to a different solution.

**Edit:** I'm connecting to SQL 2005. Looks like this is a connection provider issue, then, because Marc's suggestion to translate to a List doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Try putting the keys into a simple list and using Contains:

```
var keys = MyDictionary.Keys.ToList();

DataContext.Table.Any(res => keys.Contains(res.field1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no change - FWIW I'm connecting to SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting with this version? (It can't be the same as the ContainsKey one and 2005/2008 providers can't independently generate "no supported translation" exceptions).